# How to combine two projects in xcode?

Tags: xcode4.5

I have two projects in xcode: first one contains frameworks for getting a JSON from web (i'm using ASIHTTPRequest + SBJSON. I spent alot of time to make it works, because i'm a noob). and the second one is a custom tableview GUI which I'm going to use for represent JSON data from first project.

Is there any easy way to combine these two projects? I can't belive I must spend my time adding and setting up all JSON+ASIHTTPRequest frameworks into the second project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say that xcode allows to copy classes from one project to an other simply by dragging them in project navigator. It seems like this is the only way to combine functionality from several projects. Easy enough for me.

It's also possible to copy all frameworks from one project to an other (again by dragging and drop).

My problem is solved!